# Can't find the way to have diffent content from differents view function in a inheritance template in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm new working with Django and there's something I need to do that looks simple but can't do it yet.  Here is the issue, I have the idea to create a big project with a lot of templates and want to have same bar with username include in all templates.  So I create a `base.html` template with some content like the username and some others.   Also I have a `child.html` with another content like a cities list who extends my base.html.
My problem is that when I run my `child.html` template the views function content in my `base.html` like the username doesn't show.
Here is what I am doing:

My View for the username :

```
def userview(request):
    a = User.objects.get(pk=1)
    return render(request,'base.html',{'a': a})
```

My base.html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{a.username}}
    <div id="sidebar">
        {% block sidebar %}
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My view for cities list:

```
def regionesli(request):
    regioneslista = Regiones.objects.all()
    return render(request,'child.html',{"resultados": regioneslista})
```

My Child.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}My amazing blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% for entry in resultados %}
    <p>{{ entry.nombre_region }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to print the current user, then a `user` template variable should be available if the correct template context processor is active. Just call `{{ user.username }}` in your template. No need to pass a `User` object into the context. Relevant doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth).

But if for some reason, you have to pass a totally different object, then your cities list view code must also pass the same object. This is because in your sample code, the context variables are not inherited, so you must do something like this.

```
def userview(request):
    a = SomeObject
    return render(request,'base.html',{'a': a})

def regionesli(request):
    a = SomeObject
    regioneslista = Regiones.objects.all()
    return render(request,'child.html',{'resultados': regioneslista, 'a': a})
```

If you want a more DRY way to do it i.e. inherit not only templates but also context variables, then I suggest you study [Class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/). If implemented as such, it will look something like this:

```
class UserView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'path/to/base.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['a'] = SomeObject
        return context

class CitiesListView(UserView):
    template_name = 'path/to/child.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # context['a'] will be available once you call the next line
        context = super(CitiesListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['resultados'] = Regiones.objects.all()
        # You can add more context variables here
        return context
```

It may look like more code, but the difference is if the cities list view inherits from the user view, then the context variables are also inherited, and it helps a lot if there are plenty of context variables to inherit.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If my answer was of great help to you, please accept this as the answer for the benefit of others. Thanks!